# changing variables inside of addEventListener

Tags: javascript, variables, addeventlistener

This is my problem, I am trying to add new coordinates into a 2D array when the mouse is pressed, but I can not find out how to successfully access variables inside the event listener. I have tried a few methods, but I could not find out how to make it work.

```
myGameArea.canvas.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var MousesX = event.clientX+55;
        var MousesY = event.clientY+55;
    }, false);
ConnectionAdd(MouseX,MouseY,Connections,viewH);
```

Here is what it says

> ReferenceError: MouseX is not defined
>       at draw

Btw that was the most basic test, but it best describes what I want to do.

Comment: `ConnectionAdd(MouseX,MouseY,Connections,viewH);` is outside of your event listener callback function, so MouseX and MouseY have lost scope.

Comment: MouseX and MouseY is in another scope, you need to create them outside the callback function.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just define them outside the click event the set them inside like this:

```js
var MousesX = 0
var MousesY = 0
document.getElementById('demo').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  MousesX = e.clientX + 55;
  MousesY = e.clientY + 55;
  console.log(MousesX)
  console.log(MousesY)
}, false);
document.getElementById('demo2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log(MousesX)
  console.log(MousesY)
}, false);
```

```html
<p id="demo">asdf</p>
<p id="demo2">demo2 first click is zeros clicks will be what  was stored on the last demo click</p>
```

Comment: That's pretty useless as you never know when they change.

Comment: If he wants to use them outside of that scope it will have the value from the last click and it is what he wants to do...

Comment: Sorry, my question was super simple, I'm just learning HTML and javascript, and just so you know, demo one was what I wanted.

Comment: But this demo doesn't work. You will have problems with this code.

Comment: It will work if those are the only two variables that ConnectionAdd can not see

Answer (score -1):

OK... First, you forgot to add `event` argument to your callback:

```
myGameArea.canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var MousesX = event.clientX+55;
  var MousesY = event.clientY+55;
}, false);
ConnectionAdd(MouseX,MouseY,Connections,viewH);
```

Second, you have to move your ConnectionAdd function
inside the callback. Not only because outside that callback your variables MouseX and MouseY are not reachable, but mainly because that function must be executed asynchronously also, so when the callback is fired, and not immediately after the event listener definition.

```
myGameArea.canvas.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var MousesX = event.clientX+55;
  var MousesY = event.clientY+55;
  ConnectionAdd(MouseX,MouseY,Connections,viewH);
}, false);
```

Comment: You did not "just" add an event argument to the callback. You also moved the `ConnectionAdd` function invocation inside the callback's body.

Comment: The code here is correct, so I don't want to post a new answer with the same code, but your explanation of the problem and solution is incomplete. It doesn't address the specific error he's getting at all.